# Pre-trained Model Not Loading

Tags: pytorch, pre-trained-model, image-enhancement

i have a codeformer pre-trained model from sczhou and i am trying to use that pre-trained model in my project, iam trying to use it since 20 days but i got module import error evrytime i don't know how can i fix this if anyone know about pytorch nad pre-tyrained model and how to load in api. anyone's response must appriceated.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('*')
import torch


from basicsr.models.codeformer_model import CodeFormerModel
# Instantiate CodeFormerModel
model = CodeFormerModel(__name__)


# Load the pretrained model weights
model_path = '*'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu')))

# Set the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()
```

i am expecting that i can use this pre-trained model in. my project through api but i can not found any way to use it in api or developing an api using codeformer pre-trained model
`your text`

Comment: What is the error? Please provide the full error.

Comment: I am Working on a pre-trained model "CodeFormer" and developing an API for the app. but when I'm trying to call API my terminal throws me a module error let me show you

**    from routes.api_routes import routes
  File "/Users/macm2/Desktop/Cyan-DL-II/api/routes/api_routes.py", line 6, in <module>
    from model.models import load_model
  File "/Users/macm2/Desktop/Cyan-DL-II/api/model/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from CodeFormer.weights.CodeFormer import codeformer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CodeFormer'
**
@Ivan